# Need help tagging in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to sort this data in the best way I can, column B cells exist in multiple categories under column A. Therefore I would like to tag all the column B cells with their corresponding column A cells so I can sort the column B A-Z and see which column B cell has been present in the column A cells, and how many times, so I can delete some of the unnecessary multiples.

Some of the cells in column A are presented multiple times under column A categories, which I am trying to see which ones and how many times, so I can delete some of them.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: need help]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tagging column B cells to identify their column A counterparts, this functionality is built into Excel's custom sort.

Highlight both columns, click 'Sort & Filter' > 'Custom Sort...'. In the popup, you can add different sorting levels to do what I think you're trying to do. Sort first by column A, then add a new level to sort by column B.

Hope that helps!